# Java - implement iterator with strategy

Tags: java, design-patterns, iterator, composite, strategy-pattern

I am trying to implement a custom iterator for a composite class and use different strategies in the iterator implementation depending on how the client wants to traverse the composite structure.

```
public class MyComposite implements Iterable<MyComponent> {

    ArrayList<MyComponent> childComponents;

    //MyComposite methods

    @Override
    public Iterator<MyComponent> iterator() {
        return new MyIterator(this);
    }
}
```

I would like to pass a `MyIteratorStrategy` object as part of the iterator construction, however the `Iterable` interface does not permit passing objects to the `iterator` method.

```
public class SomeClient {
    private void traverseComposite() {
        MyComposite myComposite = new MyComposite();

        MyIteratorStrategy fooStrategy = new MyIteratorStrategy("foo");
        MyIteratorStrategy barStrategy = new MyIteratorStrategy("bar");

        MyIterator fooIterator = myComposite.iterator(fooStrategy);
        MyIterator barIterator = myComposite.iterator(barStrategy);     
    }
}
```

Here's how I'm utilizing the strategy in the iterator implementation:

```
public class MyIterator implements Iterator<MyComponent> {

    MyComponent component;
    MyIteratorStrategy strategy;

    public MyIterator(MyComponent component, MyIteratorStrategy strategy) {
        this.component = component;
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    @Override
    public Component next() {
        if(strategy.isDone(component) {
            //return some child component
        } else {
            //return some other child component
        }
    }

    //rest of implementation
}
```

I'm trying to learn how to utilize design patterns, so perhaps I'm being overly general. How can I cleanly inject the strategy into the iterator?

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you have posted code on here without specifying what is wrong with it.  We expect to see what you expect the code to do, why you expect it to do this, what it is actually doing, and why it is wrong.  Please [edit] your question to include this information, and then I will consider retracting my downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JoeC My question clearly states what is wrong with the code posted above - "I would like to pass a `MyIteratorStrategy` object as part of the iterator construction, **however the Iterable interface does not permit passing objects to the iterator method.**"

Comment: Then I think you need to reconsider whether `Iterable<?>` is the right interface to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Change `MyIterator` to be the class that implements `Iterable<MyComponent>`, instead of `Iterator`.  (You might want to rename it something like `MyComponentScanner` for clarity.)

Move the `public Iterator<MyComponent> iterator()` method over from the `MyComposite` class to `MyIterator` (or whatever you rename it).

Example...

```
public class MyComponentScanner implements Iterable<MyComponent> {

    MyComponent component;
    MyIteratorStrategy strategy;

    public MyComponentScanner(MyComponent component, MyIteratorStrategy strategy) {
        this.component = component;
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<MyComponent> iterator() {
        return new Iterator() {
            @Override
            public Component next() {
                if(strategy.isDone(component) {
                    //return some child component
                } else {
                    //return some other child component
                }
            }
        };
    }

    //rest of implementation
}
```